# Error handling HTML Script tag

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder whether we have any error notification for `'<script src="....."></script>'`

Basically, I wanted to load another file if script failed to load given src.
I can do that by sending an ajax request, but do not want to, if `<script>` itself have some error mechanism.

Comment: The `script` tag has no internal mechanism for doing this, no.

Comment: ok. So only alternate is send AJAX request and if it fails then do something. right?

Comment: @Jonathan, what about the [error event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)?

Comment: @extjsuser Not necessarily. Most likely, the file will have a global variable or global reference in it. Check for the reference and then load something else if the reference is missing. (i.e. if you were loading jQuery from a CDN for example `<script src="cdn-path/jquery.min.js"></script><script>if(!window.jQuery) { .. do some logic here .. }</script>`)

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have access to file, URL is provided by third party, and so if is not exist, I add my own.

Answer (score 2):

have a go with this script

```
<script>
 var s = document.createElement("script");
 s.onerror=function() {
   var s1=document.createElement("script");
   s1.src="myown.js";
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s1);
 }
 s.onload=function() {
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
 }
 s.src="http://somewhere.com/script.js";
</script>
```

Comment: does this solution works with any script tags ? for e.g. google maps -> can the errors (due to map loading failure or any related to maps usually we see in console) be caught using [onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) as it seems to support in all the browers? thanks :)

Comment: I should work with all scripts- the map loading failure needs to be tested

Comment: Thank you .... Is there a way to test it  or any other alternatives you know to catch such ?